# Url Encode Function in WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi, wininet

Does WinAPI/WinINet have a function that can url encode a string?

I am posting data that contains '=', '&', ' ', etc. and these are conflicting with the post variables. If not any idea of any implementations of url encoding in c/c++?

Comment: `InternetCanonicalizeUrl`

Comment: @JonathanPotter is there a flag or another function that can convert `=` characters aswell? The above function works for `[`, `&` and etc. which is good but not `=`.

Comment: @JakeM `=` does not need to be encoded in a URL per RFC 3986, which is also used for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` submissions in HTML.

Comment: @JonathanPotter That doesn't just url-encode. It canonicalises a URL.